# How to install pandas using PIP for AWS Web Services written in Python

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pip, python-3.8

I'm installing Pandas to work with CSV files in AWS API's written in Python. And getting build errros.

Code in my build spec file:

```
  - npm install
  - pip install --target [FILE_PATH] pandas
  - pip install --target [FILE_PATH] lxml
  - pip install --target [FILE_PATH] zeep
  - pip install --target [FILE_PATH] xlrd
  - pip install --target [FILE_PATH] requests
```

Error information:

[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

```
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
```

Please note and check the following:

- The Python version is: Python3.8 from "/var/lang/bin/python3.8"
- The NumPy version is: "1.19.0"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Comment: Have you tried using `pip3` ?

Comment: Refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62275875/5424128

Comment: Thank you Marcin and Paradigm! I changed Python version to Python3.7 and it worked. So looks like latest Pandas version (1.19.0) is not compatible with Python3.8.